# Union of Callables vs Callable with a union return type

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, mypy, pylance

I've got code in the form of:

```
def x() -> Union[str,int]:
    return ...

l: list[Union[Callable[[], str], Callable[[], int]]] = [x]
```

Both MyPy and Pylance throw errors here, that the types are incompatible:

```
Expression of type "list[() -> (str | int)]" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[(() -> str) | (() -> int)]"
  Type "() -> (str | int)" cannot be assigned to type "(() -> str) | (() -> int)"
    Type "() -> (str | int)" cannot be assigned to type "() -> str"
      Function return type "str | int" is incompatible with type "str"
        Type "str | int" cannot be assigned to type "str"
          "int" is incompatible with "str"
    Type "() -> (str | int)" cannot be assigned to type "() -> int"
      Function return type "str | int" is incompatible with type "int"
        Type "str | int" cannot be assigned to type "int"
```

The type of the list is determined by another library, so it's necessarily a union of two different callable types. Is there a way to change the type of `x` to be a union of callable (rather than a callable that returns a union type)?

Surely there should be a way of making this work without ignoring type safety. How can I type-hint this code, or manipulate this code, so MyPy and Pylance agree it's correct? If `x` is one line, than it could be written as a lambda, but suppose `x` were longer than one line.

Answer (score 3):

The type checkers are not being overly cautious here. A function that returns a union type cannot be safely coerced to a union of function types.

If `x` has the type `Union[Callable[[], str], Callable[[], int]`, then `[x(), x()]` is a homogenous list, either of strings or of integers. If all you know is that `x` has the type `Callable[[], Union[str, int]]`, then `[x(), x()]` might contain a string and an integer.

If you have control over all the code, then the best solution is typically to make the type of `l` more general. It's a heterogeneous list, where elements might return either `int` or `str`. The code that consumes `l` can typically cope with individual elements not always returning the same type (in a lot of cases, the code is just consuming one element at a time).

If you can't change the type of `l` because it's in a library, then your `x` function does not meet the declared requirements of the library. If you know that the library's type annotations are overly cautious, go ahead and lie with a cast. If you don't know for sure that the library relies on the more specific type, redesign `x`.

Comment: I don't think we know that `[x(), x()]` is a homogenous list. Consider the (admittedly diabolical) example:

```
def y():
    global x
    x = lambda: 3
    return "s"
x = y
print([x(), x()])
```

Pylance doesn't seem to have any type safety issue here. And it shouldn't - `x` is either a function that returns a string, or a function that returns an int, so there's no reason we can assert that `[x(), x()]` is homogenous. (Of course, we could come up with a less diabolical example for any real world case where x() is called at different points in our code.)

Comment: @AMWJ Oh, indeed, to know that `[x(), x()]` is homogeneous you also have to know that `x` isn't mutated, which I don't think any existing Python type checker tries to take into account. But it's still a property that the type would guarantee. You write “x is either a function that returns a string, or a function that returns an int” — well, if you want to express that, you need to change the type of `x` to `Union[Callable[[], str], Callable[[], int]`, instead of the more general type in the code snippet your question.

Answer (score 0):

You've said that `x` could return a `str` or an `int`. For example,

```
def x() -> Union[str, int]:
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        return 3
    else:
        return "foo"
```

What's the type of `x` itself?

- It's not `Callable[[], str]`, because it could return 3, an `int`.
- It's not `Callable[[], int]`, because it could return `"foo"`, a `str`.

As such, you cannot add it to `l`, which you've said only contains functions that have one of the two above types.

`x` has type `Callable[[], str|int]`, because no matter what `x` returns, it's either a `str` or an `int`.

Note that the static return type can be more general than the return type in practice:

```
# OK - 3 isn't *not* a str or an int
def y() -> Union[str, int]:
    return 3
```

but it cannot be more *specific*

```
# Not OK. No matter how unlikely it is that `y` will return an string,
# it *might* return a string.
def y() -> int:
    p = random.randint(1, 100000000000000000000000000000000)
    if p == 1:
        return 3
    else:
        return "foo"
```